# Limit urls to a domain - Django

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I need to lock down various urls to a certain domain.

Any ideas?

Comment: You'll get better help if you actually say what you want to do. What URLs? What domain? How will this affect the user? What are you actually talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the view, check the [get_host](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.get_host) result on the request. If it's a bad host, return either HttpResponseNotFound or HttpResponseForbidden (depending on your specific need).

Edit: perhaps you want to lock down based on the client domain. Then you should check REMOTE_HOST.

Answer (score 1):

You could also consider altering URLconf per request, in custom middleware, depending on request domain (i.e. `request.get_host()`). 
Documentation is here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.urlconf .